# Solr cloud client 5.3.1 Timeout Exception while using with spring hibernate transaction

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj, spring-transactions, solrcloud

I was connecting the solr to index some database entries that i am getting with spring hibernate transaction. But facing the below exception.

```
Error while calling watcher 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ExecutorUtil.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$3.process(SolrZkClient.java:261)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:522)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498) 


org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper x.x.x.x:8000 within 10000 ms
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.(SolrZkClient.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.(SolrZkClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.(SolrZkClient.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.(ZkStateReader.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.connect(CloudSolrClient.java:465)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(CloudSolrClient.java:822)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.request(CloudSolrClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:86)


CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient = null;
TransactionStatus transactionStatus = null;
List levelDefinitions = new LinkedList();
try
{
    DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    transactionStatus = getTransactionManager().getTransaction(transactionDefinition);

    //database query

    cloudSolrClient = new CloudSolrClient("x.x.x.x:8000");

    cloudSolrClient.setDefaultCollection("CMD_OUSTR_NEW_dev");
    SolrInputDocument solrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument();

     //field setting of SolrInputDocument 

    LinkedList solrInputDocuments = new LinkedList();
    solrInputDocuments.add(solrInputDocument);

    cloudSolrClient.add(solrInputDocuments);

    cloudSolrClient.commit();

    getTransactionManager().commit(transactionStatus);
```

NOTE: the same solr code is working if spring hibernate transaction is not getting opened in the thread.

Comment: You can create CloudSolrClient with a list of the available Zookeeper hosts - giving it all the available hosts would probably be helpful. Might be a limitation on the number of active connections to Zookeeper?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue resolved**

The issue was due to incompatible log4j implementation for MDC inside a activemq jar version 5.8 and we are using MDC for transaction logging. We were putting a map for transaction info that ExcecutorUtil(line 172) of solrj jar 
is casting into String for getting submitter context.

Replaced the jar with 5.10 version. Now its working